# Streaming Video via Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, video, mobile

Right now my task is to stream a video from a site like this http://watchers.to/sazktfmnvzqc.html on an iPhone. (Be warned, there are tons of pop ups)

I've tried using a UIWebView to simply open up a portal for clicking the video at that URL, but honestly they're so many pop ups its actually impossible.

Is there any clever way to circumvent this that you all can think of? Like code that I could use to instantly click underneath the popup overlay or even click on the overlay the required amount of times, instantly reloading back from the new page to stream the video? Just looking for a direction to go.

Thanks!

Comment: Parse the HTML with a library such as Fuzi then extract the video URL and use it in AVPlayer.

Comment: On that page, is there actually an exact "video URL"? I can't find it.

Comment: So essentially the most reduced element I can find is the flash player for the video '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://watchers.to/player7/jwplayer.flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="vplayer_swf_0" name="vplayer_swf_0" class="jw-swf jw-reset" style="display: block; position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px;" sj4z73nmqpra0yp="wVuj1nJJYf7Kv3R" data-bjppopads-handled="1"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param</object>'

Comment: If the HTML doesn't contain an actual link to a video, there's no way to use AVPlayer. :/ I just had a quick look but apparently they're using JS and not static URLs, this looks like a dead end indeed.

Comment: Well to get around that I was using a UIWebview which does let you play the video, it just takes a profound amount of links

Comment: Similarly, open the Chrome Developer Tools window go to the Network tab and see what resources are being fetched. This can frequently yield results faster than parsing code.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know the exact URL of the video. Then you can use an `AVPlayerViewController`, which needs an `AVPlayer` initialised with this URL.

Example:

```
import AVFoundation // this you need for the `AVPlayer`
import AVKit // this is for the `AVPlayerViewController`

let viewController = AVPlayerViewController()
let videoURL = "http://you.videourl.com"

if let player = AVPlayer.playerWithURL(videoURL) as? AVPlayer {
    viewController = player
}
```

Then you can push the view controller and play the video.

Comment: Unfortunately the video links aren't that simple. I've tried that method and it doesn't work. Click on the link I posted to get a better idea. I'm not super familiar with web media jargon but I think that video is a streaming component as opposed to a general file.

Answer (score 1):

I got if from here.
Worked for me.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MediaPlaybackGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html

```
func play (){
    //Your video path URL
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.xxx.xxx/xx/xxxx/xxxxxxx.mov") else {return}

    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
    self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: `url` should be unwrapped with a `guard` or `if let` statement here, not force-unwrapped as an argument to the AVPlayer initializer.